# Ambiguous characters appear when sending e-mail from Android application using Indy in the Subject and Sender's name

Tags: android, email, delphi, unicode, indy

I'm trying to send an e-mail to a Gmail account using Indy 10.6 `TIdMessage` in a Delphi 10.4.2 Android FMX application.

However, ambiguous characters appear (`?`) in the `Subject` and `From.Name` for Turkish chars `ğŞşÖŞÜĞİÜ`.

Meanwhile, the message body appears correctly for both environments when sending from Windows or Android. For example, if the `Subject` is `"ÇĞÜÇÖŞQçöİŞİiIıĞğÇöÜüĞğiüiÜ"` when sending, that appears as `"Ç?ÜÇÖ?Qçö???iI???ÇöÜü??iüiÜ"` in the e-mail. This does not occur when compiling as a Windows application, just on Android.

Similarly, if the `Sender.Name` includes specials char then in the e-mail it appears with `?` chars, but the message body text appears correctly on e-mails.

Please take a look at the code below, which are standard codes to send e-mail using Indy.

```
//variable definitions have been done


begin
...
...
...
  TTask.Run(procedure begin

  try
    TThread.Synchronize ( nil, procedure begin
      self.recAniInd.Visible := True;
      self.recAniInd.Opacity := 0.0;
      self.recAniInd.Visible := True;
      self.lbMessage.Text    := 'Mail gönderiliyor...';
      TAnimator.AnimateFloat( self.recAniInd, 'Opacity', 0.50, 0.3 );
    end );

    LAddress := IdMessage.Recipients.Add;
    LAddress.Address := 'somemail@gmail.com';
    //LMessage.BccList.Add.Address := '';

    subject:= 'ÇĞÜÇÖŞQçöİŞİiIıĞğÇöÜüĞğiüiÜ';//#$C3#$B6+#$C3#$B6+#$c3#$9c; //ÖÖÜ testing the chars

    with IdGlobal.IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault do
     subject :=  GetString(GetBytes(subject));

    plt := 'AND'; // or WIN
    txtSubject.Text  := subject;                // to test
    txtUserName.Text := subject + ',' + plt;    // to test 

    FromName := txtUserName.Text;
    IdMessage.From.Name    :=  (FromName);      //Not shows correctly in the e-mail
    IdMessage.From.Address := 'from_mail@gmail.com'; 
    IdMessage.Date         := now;
    IdMessage.ContentType  := 'text/plain';

    IdMessage.CharSet      := 'UTF-8';
    IdMessage.Encoding     := mePlainText;

    IdMessage.Subject       := subject;           //Not shows correctly in the e-mail
    IdMessage.Body.Assign( Memo2.Lines );

    {$ifdef ANDROID}
     fname1                := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'studentinfo.json';
     fname2                := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'txtFile.txt';
    {$ENDIF}

    {$ifdef MSWINDOWS}
     fname1                := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + 'studentinfo.json';
     fname2                := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0))) + 'txtFile.txt';
    {$ENDIF}

    Attachment1           := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, fname1);
    Attachment2           := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(IdMessage.MessageParts, fname2);

    try
     IdSMTP1.Connect;
     try
      IdSMTP1.Send(IdMessage);
     finally
      IdSMTP1.Disconnect;

     end;
    except
     on E: Exception do begin
      IdSMTP1.Disconnect;
      TThread.Synchronize(nil, procedure begin
        Memo1.Lines.Append(E.Message);
        self.recAniInd.Opacity := 0.4;
        self.recAniInd.Visible := True;
        self.lbMessage.Text    := 'Mail sent error!';
        TAnimator.AnimateFloat( self.recAniInd, 'Opacity', 0.0, 0.3 );
      end);
     end;
    end;

  finally
   if Assigned(Attachment1) then Attachment1.Free;
   if Assigned(Attachment2) then Attachment2.Free;

   TThread.Synchronize( nil, procedure begin
        self.recAniInd.Visible := True;
        self.recAniInd.Opacity := 0.4;
        self.recAniInd.Visible := True;
        self.lbMessage.Text    := 'Mail sent. OK.';
        TAnimator.AnimateFloat( self.recAniInd, 'Opacity', 0.0, 0.3 );
        self.recAniInd.Visible := False;
   end);//TThread.Synchronize
  end;//try

  end);//TTask
...
...
...
end;
```

I also tried to encode the `Subject` and `From.Name` as many encoding types, but could not show the Turkish chars correctly. The `SendMsg()` code in the unit `IdSMTPBase` (tracing over the `SendPipelining()` function and other sub functions) makes some encoding related to the OS, but in this case it could not show correct chars in the e-mail.

How can I correct the chars appearing wrong (or showed as `?`) in the e-mail?

Edit:
Saved IdMessage data (I've saved the IdMessage after sending e-mail) is below:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
From:
 =?UTF-8?B?w4fEnsOcw4fDlsWeUcOnw7bEsMWexLBpScSxxJ7En8OHw7bDnMO8xJ7En2nD?=
 =?UTF-8?B?vGnDnCxXSU4=?=
 <ftspuni@gmail.com>
Subject:
 =?UTF-8?B?w4fEnsOcw4fDlsWeUcOnw7bEsMWexLBpScSxxJ7En8OHw7bDnMO8xJ7En2nD?=
 =?UTF-8?B?vGnDnA==?=
To: someunimail@gmail.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2021 02:45:19 +0300

asds dasdas

begin 660 studentinfo.json
M>R)O9W)E;F-I0613;WEA9"(Z(EQU,#!#-T564D4@7'4P,$,W159212!<=3`P
M0S=%5E)%(%QU,#!#-T564D4B+")O9W).;R(Z(C$Q,3$Q,3$Q,3$Q,3$B+")B
M;VQU;2(Z(EQU,#!#-V5V<F4@32XB+")N3U])3R(Z,"PB97!O<W1A(CHB05-$
M05-$041`4T131$8N0T]-+E12(BPB8V%L:7-M86QA<B(Z(EQU,#!#-T564D4@
M4R!&7'4P,$,W4T9$(%QU,#!#-U-$1T8@4V0Z(%QR7&Y31D1'(%QU,#!#-U-$
M9SI<=3`P0S<@<V9D7'4P,$,W(',Z1T9$7')<;E-D.F8@<V9D.B!D<SI<=3`P
50S=&1R`Z9'-'.F1S7'4P,$4W.B)]
`
end

begin 660 txtFile.txt
&9&5N96UE
`
end

.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Get rid of your calls to `IdGlobal.IndyTextEncoding_OSDefault`, they don't belong in this code and can corrupt your Unicode strings. Just assign your `subject` string as-is to the `TIdMessage.Subject`. Same with the `From.Name`, `Sender.Name`, frankly *any* string property. `TIdMessage` will encode the strings using UTF-8 by default in Delphi 2009+. You can override that, if needed, by using the various `Charset` properties for body text, and the `TIdMessage.OnInitializeISO` event for header text.

Comment: More importantly, for Android specifically, Indy uses the underlying platform's iconv library when using Delphi, but was [recently updated](https://www.atozed.com/forums//thread-2269-post-7720.html) to not use iconv anymore when using FreePascal, as iconv has problems on Android 10. So that may or may not be playing into your issue. Are you using the stock Indy that shipped with Delphi 10.4.2, or are you using an updated version from [Indy's GitHub repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Remy. Yes, this is the stock Indy coming with D104.2, i'll try update and test, but in my case just From.Name, Sender.Name are erroneous and body text is showed correct with all chars in the e-mail. I traced over the sendmsg() api in the Indy and saw that body text bas been encoded a-bit different than the header parts.

Comment: like I said, Indy uses UTF-8 by default when encoding headers (verify with the `TIdMessage.OnInitializeISO` event). Please [edit] your question to show the raw email data that `TIdMessage` is generating.

Comment: On a side note - `TTask` runs in a worker thread, so you MUST synchronize with the main UI thread when accessing your UI controls, even for read access.

Comment: I've tested the e-mail send fmx mobile app using the latest Indy from github (updating Indy10). Results are the same, some chars apperas as ? like this in the subject field:  "Ç?ÜÇÖ?Qçö???iI???ÇöÜü??iüiÜ" (whic should be "ÇĞÜÇÖŞQçöİŞİiIıĞğÇöÜüĞğiüiÜ". Any solution or idea?

Comment: IdMessage data is updated in my question, please you can look at.

Comment: decoding the raw email data you have shown, the `From` header decodes as `ÇĞÜÇÖŞQçöİŞİiIıĞğÇöÜüĞği iÜ,WIN`, and the `Subject` header decodes as `ÇĞÜÇÖŞQçöİŞİiIıĞğÇöÜüĞği iÜ`. So Indy is actually encoding the characters you claim it is not. So something else is going on, likely with the receiver, not the sender.

Comment: On a side note, when attachments are present, the `TIdMessage.Encoding` should be set to `meMIME`, not `mePlainText`. Nobody uses plain-text attachments anymore, that format was mainly used back in the days of Usenet newsgroups before MIME became popular. The `Encoding` is `meDefault` by default, you should leave it as that value, and let `TIdMessage` decide how best to encode its content.